# a question about limit, I am struggling with this!

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Suppose that {$a_n$}is a sequence of positive numbers.For each n which is a natural number,let
$b_n$=($a_1+a_2+......a_n$)/n,prove that $\sum b_n$ diverges to $+\infty$.

This question is my homework, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation might help

Comment: Hint: look up Harmonic series

Comment: I think they don't work

Comment: Suppose you have a sequence $c_n = 1$ for all n. Let $d_n = (c_1+c_2+...c_n)/n$. then $d_n = 1$ for all n. $\sum d_n$ clearly diverges to infinity as n goes to infinity. Since $a_n>c_n$ for all n, we know that $b_n>d_n$ for all n. so $\sum b_n$ also diverges.

Comment: Wait just to check... can the a's be any positive real number, or are they integers?

Comment: No, it is any positive real numbers instead of integers

Comment: ah ok. Then my comment is wrong, since I assumed the a's are integers.

Comment: Ok. When calculating the sum $\sum b_n$, I get the form: $(1+1/2+1/3+...)a_1 + (1/2+1/3+...)a_2+...$. Since the series 1/n diverges, the coefficient of $a_1$ goes to infinity, $\sum b_n$ must go to infinity also. Can someone else check if this makes sense.

Comment: you can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating the sum $\sum b_n$, I get the form: $(1+1/2+1/3+...)a_1 + (1/2+1/3+...)a_2+...$. Since the series 1/n diverges, the coefficient of $a_1$ goes to infinity, $\sum b_n$ must go to infinity also.

Comment: Ok, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If $\{a_n\}$ diverges, then obviously $\{b_n\}$ will not be bounded, and therefore $\sum b_n$ diverges.

Otherwise, $\{a_n\}$ converges to some value $l$. It is a theorem that if this is the case, then $b_n$ must also converge to $l$. Since every term of $\{a_n\}$ is positive, we must have $l > 0$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n \neq 0$, and then the vanishing condition then implies that $\sum b_n$ diverges.